# Drawing 2D in Blender

Tags: grease-pencil

I was wondering

[image]

There was this image on Blender.org, but how to make it?

Greace pencil is sure but rendering and other I don't know

Kind regards :)

Comment: Grease Pencil is still under development and some of the images you see on line cannot be achieved using the standard Blender release. Having said that, I believe that this is all GP rendered through the OpenGL viewport.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I don't think this is made entirely with the grease pencil. For results like that you should take a look at [freestyle line rendering](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/FreeStyle).

Comment: Link to the original animation, using grease pencil: https://vimeo.com/140897174